# Can't scrape cgi image with python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, cgi

website `https://website.country/1/2/_3.html` loads this code:

`<p> There's <img alt="Title" src="/cgi/name.cgi?size=30"> People </p>`

So I see the image when I go to the website on my browser.

```
URL =  https://website.country/1/2/_3.html
GET =  https://website.country/cgi/name.cgi?size=30

with requests.session() as s:
   FIRST = s.get(URL)
   SECOND = s.get(GET)
   print(SECOND.content)
```

From this I get a [200] code and output is `b''`
If I mess with the headers I'll get a [400] response.

If I go to the source of the image (GET) on my browser it shows me nothing, as does if I request it with python.

Do you have ideas how I can scrape this image?
Comment if you think the headers would be useful to you.

Thank you!

EDIT: I want to get the bytes of the image, so when I write these bytes to a .png file I will be able to open the image.

I understand that if you have an `<img src="imgurl.sthg">` then you can retrieve the image using bs4, requests itself or urllib.

The problem that I have is that this is not the case: When I go to that url, erither through requests.get(imgsrc) or through my browser, the page doesn't give me the image

### The problem is

That the image url (here I called it GET) is being called (through a get request) by the website when it loads, but when I go to the image url it only loads  `b''`

Comment: What are you expecting to see when you "scrape the image"?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are expecting to do with the image so below is an example of how to download the the profile image on this page with requests.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import urllib

page = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59830836/cant-scrape-cgi-image-with-python-requests')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

image = tree.xpath("//img[@src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mCyTqR9AbcyZ1oMj2NCunLmhzj9Nkf6RvWiI9hX=k-s32']")

print(image[0].attrib["src"])

urllib.request.urlretrieve(image[0].attrib["src"], 'C:\\Path\\To\\filename.png')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've edited my post to make it clearer what I want to do with the image (I want to download it) and why getting it through requests is not working.